# Switch to previously opened window in selenium java - using Firefox version 56

Tags: java, selenium

I have performed some actions by opening a window in Firefox 56, I open another window and to do some operations. Once it has completed the operations in 2nd window, I need to switch back to the previously opened window.

I tried with windowHandler but its not working.

Could someone please help me with this? I'm totally new to Selenium with Java, so it would be of great help!
Thanks.

Comment: You can toggle between open tabs using Ctrl+[0-9], so if you have two open tabs, the first one would be Ctrl+1 and the second one would be Ctrl+2, so you can utilize that with sendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for the Advanced browser operations,
there is function in C#,

For the navigation history i always use :-

```
this.driver.Navigate().Back();
```

You can also store the url of previous window and again navigate to that url.

```
string oldUrl = this.driver.Url;
this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@oldUrl);
```

Helps to switch between browser windows or tabs :-

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.windowHandles;
driver.SwitchTo(windowHandles.First()); // switch to first opened window
```

can you please more specific about why windowHandles not working (any error or exception) 
if you are done with operations on second window then you should close it as you said it keeps on executing on second window,

you can also use forEach loop on windowHandles,

```
driver.Close();// close newly opened window
driver.SwitchTo(windowHandles.First()); // then switch to older window
```

or use

```
driver.Close();
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[0]);
```

Comment: No error as such. It was continuing the execution in the 2nd window instead of navigating to first window.

Comment: Thanks Ashish Kamble. The above code is working fine for me.